# Java - how to repair malformed JSON?

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm parsing one config file using the Java and Regex.

After this i get ArrayList of the strings in the following format.

[image]

And i would like to get from example above valid JSON:

```
{
    "ssid": "test1",
    "psk": "154695",
    "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
    "sim_slot": "-1",
    "imsi": "none",
    "priority": 1
}
```

How can i do it in any simple way please? Any library for this? (i must not be the JSON i can accept any other format (XML, CSV, etc..))

**EDIT:**

I tried to update the Regex by recommendation:

```
  while (m.find()) {
                    String foundOccurence = m.group();
                    foundOccurence = foundOccurence.replace("=",":");
                    foundOccurence = foundOccurence.replaceAll("\\s*([^:]+):(.*(\\n|$))","\"$1\":$2");
                    allMatches.add(foundOccurence);
                }
```

But result is still is not valid (but almost is), see image below:

[image]

Comment: Jackson can do a lot for you (in particular, its parser allows for keys not to be string literals) but as to _values_ which are not conform...

Comment: So that I am clear, you say _"I'm parsing one config file using the Java and Regex"_ - is that the file you are showing in your question? If not, could you show that file?

Comment: @SeanBright: Look at the previous OP's questions, there is more context there.

Comment: And you shouldn't parse something as complicated as JSON with regular expressions. You need a parser, and three good ones are available out of the box.

Comment: you can try to read www.json.org. you can find good examples

Comment: It is not JSON parsing, it is the opposite, make a string valid JSON string.

Comment: If this is a known bug in your config file generator, then hard code the fix in your parsing code, if you can't change the generator

Comment: What about parsing it with a [YAML parser](http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/)? Perhaps, removing the `{` lines and replacing `}` with `---` will create a valid YAML.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're really looking for.

From this input string:

> ```
> {
>     ssid:"test1"
>     psk:"test154695"
>     key_mgmt:WPA-PSK
>     sim_slot:"-1"
>     imsi:"none"
>     priority:1
> }
> ```

It seems you want to get this output string:

> ```
> {
>     "ssid": "test1",
>     "psk": "test154695",
>     "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
>     "sim_slot": "-1",
>     "imsi": "none",
>     "priority": 1
> }
> ```

The differences I see:

- Add double-quotes around key values
- Add double-quotes around the value of `key_mgmt`, turning `WPA-PSK` to `"WPA-PSK"`
- Add a space after `:`
- Add a comma after each value, except the last one

Here's an implementation to do just that, and verify.
I hope this what you were looking for,
or that based on this you will be able to figure out.

```
    String malformed = "{\n" +
            "    ssid:\"test1\"\n" +
            "    psk:\"test154695\"\n" +
            "    key_mgmt:WPA-PSK\n" +
            "    sim_slot:\"-1\"\n" +
            "    imsi:\"none\"\n" +
            "    priority:1\n" +
            "}";

    String expected = "{\n" +
            "    \"ssid\": \"test1\",\n" +
            "    \"psk\": \"test154695\",\n" +
            "    \"key_mgmt\": \"WPA-PSK\",\n" +
            "    \"sim_slot\": \"-1\",\n" +
            "    \"imsi\": \"none\",\n" +
            "    \"priority\": 1\n" +
            "}";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):([^\\n]*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(malformed);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{\n");
    while (m.find()) {
        String key = m.group(1);
        String value = m.group(2);
        if (key.equals("key_mgmt")) {
            value = "\"" + value + "\"";
        }
        builder.append(String.format("    \"%s\": %s,\n", key, value));
    }
    builder.replace(builder.length() - 2, builder.length(), "\n}");
    String corrected = builder.toString();

    assert expected.equals(corrected);
```